# When I try to convert the pandas DataFrame to Xarray dataset I get this error

Tags: python, pandas, geospatial, python-xarray, jcr-sql2

When I try to convert the pandas DataFrame to Xarray dataset I get this error:

> ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

Image:

[image]

Code:

```
# Convert the DataFrame back to xarray Dataset and assign CRS
temp_group_df.set_index(['lat', 'lon', 'month'], inplace=True)
temp_array = temp_group_df.to_xarray()
temp_array.rio.write_crs('epsg:4326', inplace=True)
display(temp_array)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not convert lists or tuples in your cells to xarray. So you can't convert your columns `burned_area` and `result`.

Convert those columns to multiple columns with single values and the conversion should work.

Comment: could you please explain this more.